Illustration of high-probability and typical set in Elements of information theory?
I'm following the book Elements of information theory by Joy A. Thomas, Thomas M. Cover. Here's the link to the text for you to understand the question: Elements of information theory
At the end of page 63, the authors point the example of $n$ i.i.d Bernoulli variables and conclude that the typical set(with small $\epsilon$, I guess) are the ones containing sequences with proportion of $1$ close to $0.9$. I'm not sure I get it.
The definition of typical set of $n$ i.i.d variables along with some $\epsilon > 0$ is basically
$$A_{\epsilon}^{(n)} = \{(x_1, ..., x_n): 2^{-n[H(B(0.9)) + \epsilon]} \leq p(x_1, ..., x_n) \leq 2^{-n[H(B(0.9)) - \epsilon]}\}$$
H(B(0.9)) is the entropy of a Bernoulli variable with parameter $0.9$. The entropy is simply
$$-0.9\log0.9 - 0.1\log0.1 \approx 0.468995$$
So, $2^{-n(0.468995 - \epsilon)} \approx 0.722^{n}$. And the probability of $p(x_1, ..., x_n)$ is approximately $0.9^{0.9n}0.1^{0.1n} \approx (1.7038)^n$.
How are these two things even close? Do we take $\epsilon$ about 1 here?

You can accept the answer if it's satisfactory

Actually I get
$$
0.9^{0.9n} 0.1^{0.1n}=(0.9^{0.9} 0.1^{0.1})^n\approx 0.72246^n
$$
so there is no contradiction.

Yes! It was mis-calculated. I calculated $0.9^{0.9} + 0.1^{0.1} \approx 1.7038$
